# HTTP Basic Auth Handler Error in Python

Tags: python, http, authentication

I am trying to login to my cPanel from python, but I always get a 401 Access Denied Code Error. I have googled, and tried, and tried, but with no success
Here is the code for the login part.

```
try:
    auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
    auth_handler.add_password("cPanel", site, base64.encodestring(user)[:-1], base64.encodestring(passwd)[:-1])
    print site,base64.encodestring(user)[:-1],base64.encodestring(passwd)[:-1]
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    urllib2.urlopen(site)
except (urllib2.HTTPError, httplib.BadStatusLine), msg:
    print msg
```

Can anyone point out to me what exactly am I doing wrong ?

URL i am passing is https://mydomain.com:2083

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you base64 encoding the username and password? auth handler will do it for you.

Comment: That's how I saw in all the examples. I tried in plain text, still the same 401 Access Denied error.

Comment: are you sure that it is using basic auth? when I go to some sites that I know use hostgator and enter hostname.com:2083, I see that they are not using basic auth. Basic auth is where your browser displays a dialog asking for username and password.